# Trying to populate custom fields in Wordpress from WP database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, custom-fields, populate

I'm trying to populate a custom field, let's say 'field_123' (in this case from ACF plugin) with data from a Wordpress database table (which is coming from an API), let's say 'house' > 'square_metres'.

Posts (cpt) are already showing the main content 'out of the box' but I would want to add some more database tables to populate other custom fields. (which I then can use later on on different grids in visual composer)

I started with something but then realized soon enough I wasn't gonna solve the problem myself..

````
  global $wpdb;

  $new_value = $_POST['acf']['field_123'];

  $wpdb->update(
    "house",
    array(
      "square_metres" => $new_value,
    ),
    array( '%s' )
  );
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_field', 1);```

Someone any suggestions? Or a push in the right direction? Perhaps there are smarter/easier ways to achieve this.

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

Is it all on the same DB? "house" is an existing table? what's it's name on the database? are you sure you didn't call it "wp_house"? in that case you are missing $wpdb->prefix."house" as the table name.

That last row of "add_action" is confusing me, what were you exactly trying to do? With that code, if the "house" table exist, you whould be able to populate its square_metres value with what you have in $new_value just fine (**be careful, you didn't specify any WHERE clause, you are going to update ALL the rows in a single shot, dunno if this was intentional**).

Is your post missing a piece of code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ehh yeah the code is far from complete, I was starting with this and like I said, then realized i wasn't able to finish it.. Database name is admin_tw and yes it's all in the same database.

Comment: So you would recommend something else to get the database content inside the custom fields? (because of the 'single shot' you mentioned)?